# How to create Scatter plot from multiindex groupby dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

[image: My dataframe looks like this]

and I want to have scatter plot that have the monthly_base_price as x axis and avg_vacancy of all the shared bedrooms in one color and avg_vacancy of all the private bedrooms in one color.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  This site isn't meant for "How do I do this?" questions.  If you've made an attempt and it's not working as intended, we can help you with that.  Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for further information.

Answer (score 0):

First I am reseting the index and creating 2 groups for shared and private with `query`.

```
shared = df.reset_index().query("bedrooms == 'shared'")
private = df.reset_index().query("bedrooms == 'private'")
```

Then I plot a chart for each of the groups.

```
ax = shared.plot(kind='scatter', x='monthly_base_price', y='avg_vacancy', label='shared')
private.plot(kind='scatter', x='monthly_base_price', y='avg_vacancy', label='privacy', ax=ax)
```